# My cat peed on my clothes!

Tags: cats, pet-selection

Ok so my cat is literally my favorite “person” in The world. We both absolutely love each other. So my cat was getting a little on the heavy side so I switched to a healthy food a year back- she hated it so I mixed it with he normal brand. She will always eat around the healthy stuff and eat the bad stuff first, if she had her way she would never eat the healthy kind. But I try to not give her any more until she finishes all her food or at least eats a lot of it. In the last day I found that she would not eat her healthy food. She like would not eat it. So I just didn’t give her any new food until she finished if. All day she was trying to get me to feed her the good food. Keep in mind this has kinda been a struggle for a year now. So I lock her in tvs room that her food is in for like 30 minutes. I comfy bsck in a d let her out not really thinking about.... I come back in that night to get in to pjs (which are in laundry basket) to find that she Peed in them!  She has pooped to show me she is mad at me a couple times but she has never peed. I’m pretty mad... please help

Comment: did your cat have a litterbox in the room,cats do not poop or pee to show they are mad at you any more than you poop or pee to show emotions.

Comment: If she starts peeing in inappropriate places more often, you should let a vet check her for urinary disease. Otherwise I would suggest trying out different brands of healthy food. Maybe you'll find some that your cat likes.

Comment: Welcome to pets.se Elidy! Please check out the answers posted in the questions I have attached to yours. They should have the answers you are looking for :)